# Inject IProgress<string> to a method passed by parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, progress

I would develop a simple Windows Forms form, contaning a Text area, an OK button and one Cancel button. I would receive a method as a constructor parameter, which I know that it has both `IProgress<string>` and a `CancellationToken` parameters, alongside another parameters.

However, both `IProgress<string>` handler (that will write progress messages on the text area I mentioned above) and the `CancellationToken` (that will be bound with Cancel button) are inside the form and not accessible from outside.

How could I "inject" both `IProgress` and `CancellationToken` to a method, before it starts? Should I make both public and tie them together before showing the form, without passing that function as a constructor parameter?

Something like that:

```
var progressForm = new MyProgressForm();
// not currently working. Just a pseudo-algorithm.
progressForm.FunctionToExecute = MyFunction(param1, param2,
    progressForm.ProgressReporter, progressForm.CancellationToken);
progressForm.Show();
```

Comment: How about keep receive them as constructor parameter and expose them as public property?

Comment: progressFrom is simply a class. Add properties and methods if you want...Set and invoke them before progressForm.Show() It's up to you to determine if using a constructor approach is appropriate or exposing through public members. We can't make that assessment with what you have provided. That being said, if the token and iProgress are crucial to MyProgressForm, then pass them in as a constructor to the class MyProgressForm.

Comment: Thank you @Botonomous for your comment. `MyProgressForm` would be a `Form` (extending `System.Windows.Forms.Form`), which aims to be a kind of a generic progress reporting form.

Comment: Thank you @NiyokoYuliawan for your comment. I don't know if I could be able to reference `MyProgressForm` innards from outside at "object construction time"